# Show $(f(A))^c \subseteq f(A^c)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$
Let $A\subseteq X$ and suppose $f$ is onto.
Prove that $(f(A))^c \subseteq f(A^c)$.

This is what I did:
Let $$y\in (f(A))^c \\ y \notin f(A) \\ f^{-1}(y) \notin A \\ f^{-1}(y) \in A^c \\ y \in f(A^c)$$.

However, I don't see where the fact of $y$ being onto was used. Can someone clarify?

Comment: I'm not sure about your third step. For one thing, $f^{-1}(y)$ is a set, not a point. It shouldn't be (or not be) an element, rather a subset.

Comment: The third expression should be: $f^{-1}(\{y\})\cap A=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your proof: You can't go from 
$$y \notin f(A)$$
to
$$f^{-1}(y) \notin A$$

because $f$ is not a bijection -- $f^{-1}$ does not exist. (And if you meant $f^{-1}$ as in the "inverse image", then $\notin$ is not valid notation.)

So you have to reason more carefully. You got that $y \notin f(A)$, but you know $f$ is onto so there must exist some $b$ such that $y = f(b)$. Therefore you have
$$
f(b) \notin f(A).
$$

Now what? Is $b$ in $A$ or not?
Then, what can you say next?

Comment: I see now, but why is it not valid notation?  
I had meant the pre-image. I'm not sure what the difference would be in writing $$f(b)\notin f(A)$$ instead of writing $$y\notin f(A).$$  
Is it because the first way of expressing lets us say something like "if $b\in A$ then $f(b) \in f(A)$ but this is not true so $b\notin A$" and we wouldn't just "apply" $f^-1$ (the preimage) to both sides?

Comment: @Natash1 The pre-image $f^{-1}(y)$ is a set, not an element. It is a set of elements of $X$.

Comment: You can't apply the pre-image to both sides, that doesn't make sense. That is where you are getting confused. Overall, you really need to carefully go back to the definitions and visualize the sets $X$ and $Y$ and the map $f$ in your head or on a piece of paper.

Answer (score 2):

The condition onto enables you to write write $\exists x \in X$, such that $f(x) = y$, $x \notin A$ for your third line.

$f^{-1}$ doesn't mean the inverse function in this context, it means the preimage set and the onto condition ensure that it is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your line: $y\not\in f(A).$

Next line: $f^{-1}(y) \not\in A,$ where $f^{-1}(y)$ is the pre-image.

1)If $f$ is not surjective $ f^{-1}(y)$ could be the empty set $\emptyset.$

In this case: $f^{-1}(y) = \emptyset \subset A.$

2) If $f$ is surjective $f^{-1}(y) \not= \emptyset$ for $y \in Y.$

Hence: There is a $x \in X$ with $x \in f^{-1}(y).$

And for this $x$,  $x \not\in A$, one has:

$ f(x) = y \in f(A^c).$